# Image in LinearLayout not resizing well

Tags: android, layout, imageview, viewstub

I have a page called 'SimpleResultPage'. In this page I display a detail view from different kind of items i have in my app.

At the start of the activity I determine what kind of items it should display and based on that I hide/show `ViewStub`'s

Currently I try to display an Image in betweent two textfields and this is the code:

```
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Simple_Result_Text_Title_1"
                    style="@style/Style_Simple_Result_Title"/>
                <ViewStub
                    android:id="@+id/Image1_ViewStub"
                    android:inflatedId="@+id/Image1_Inflated_ViewStub1"
                    style="@style/Style_Simple_Result_Image"
                    android:layout="@layout/simple_list_image"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Simple_Result_Text_Text_1"
                    style="@style/Style_Simple_Result_Text"/>
```

The style for the image is this:

```
<style name="Style_Simple_Result_Image">
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:adjustViewBounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">20dp</item>
</style>
```

But somehow the image is always small and isn't showing it the way I want it to (fill the complete width and leave 20dp margin on both sides).

How should I adjust the code to make it the way I want it?

Comment: How big is the picture file? Sometimes when I've tried to use pictures that are too large it scrunches them down like that.

Comment: 180kb. it's just a screencap from the Galaxy Tab I added using the browse function

Comment: Im sorry I mean how big as in diminsions, not file size. My mistake, I should've been more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Does changing the line

```
 <item name="android:scaleType">center</item>
```

to

```
<item name="android:scaleType">center_inside</item>
```

make any difference?

Comment: Now the Image is spreaded over the full width without any margins from the left or right. Also the height doesn't scale with the width..